# Repository mirroring

Tags: maven, mirror

I'm starting with maven and is not all clear what to put in mirror `<mirrorOf></mirrorOf>` tag.
What I understood:
1> `*` means "everything"
2> `!` prepended to a name exclude that name from look-up path
3> `central` is used whan mirroring maven central

Now what I want to do is to mirror a repository that is not maven central (teamdev's one in my case), hence I have no idea towards what the field should match: `com.teamdev`, `jxbrowser` or `com.teamdev.jxbrowser`

this is what is listed on [temadev website](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/installation/maven-config.html) as maven repo:

```xml
<repository>
  <id>com.teamdev</id>
  <url>https://europe-maven.pkg.dev/jxbrowser/releases</url>
</repository>
```

and

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
  <artifactId>jxbrowser-cross-platform</artifactId>
  <version>7.21.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each artifact stored in some maven remote repository, and to have it as dependency we should include this repository definition to the project pom.xml.

Most artifacts available in Central repository and it's defined per each pom.xml by [super-pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html).

**com.teamdev**

On this page
[temadev website](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/installation/maven-config.html) mentioned, that in order to use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.teamdev.jxbrowser</groupId>
  <artifactId>jxbrowser-cross-platform</artifactId>
  <version>7.21.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

you have to add

```
<repository>
  <id>com.teamdev</id>
  <url>https://europe-maven.pkg.dev/jxbrowser/releases</url>
</repository>
```

to your pom.xml `<repositories>...</repositories>`.

**Adding a mirror**

And if you want to specify another location (artifacts download url) for `com.teamdev` repository-id, you may specify it *in your pom.xml without mirroring*.

But if your dependency contains some `<repository>` and downloads [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#transitive-dependencies) from it, you have to add a mirror to specify another url.

in your settings.xml file add:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>com.teamdev-mirror</id>
      <name>com.teamdev Mirror Repository</name>
      <url>https://your-repository-url</url>
      <mirrorOf>com.teamdev</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

> is not all clear what to put in mirror  tag

`<mirrorOf>com.teamdev</mirrorOf>` matches the `<id>com.teamdev</id>` in repository definition.

And this artifact `jxbrowser-cross-platform` should be available in your `https://your-repository-url` mirror *with all other dependencies from the original repository*.

And you have to refer your `settings.xml` file when run maven commands, e.g. if `settings.xml` present in the project root:

```
mvn clean compile -s settings.xml
```

or see more about settings reference [here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).